# retain/release issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there an issue in the statement below for retain/release;

```
xyzProp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Report error"];
```

I am getting a error which I think is for the above statement

xyzProp is a property and I am using release on it in dealloc.

Comment: Please add context, exact error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't release this object because you didn't allocate it.

The "stringWithString" method will return an autoreleased object, so you should either let it be autoreleased, or retain it and then release it.

As a general rule, you should only release objects that you create using:

- alloc
- retain
- copy
- new

Any other method will return an autoreleased object.

**EDIT:**

xyzProp is just a member variable, not a property. If you declare your property as (retain), the generated setter method will retain any new value for you. If you set the member variable directly, you should also retain anything that you didn't allocate.

Comment: Actually I am definining it as a (nonatomic,retain) prooperty. So what is the correct approach ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should not let the contents of your instance variables be autoreleased.

Comment: xyzProp is not a property, it's a backing variable, so you should retain it

Comment: Objective-C does not have *member variables*.  It has *instance variables*.

Comment: I just replaced xyzProp with self. xyzProp
But still the app seems to be crashing (BAD SIGNAL...)

Answer (score 1):

`stringWithString` with return an autoreleased string.

Although xyzProp is a property, your code is assigning the reference directly without going through the setter of xyzProp which will not increase the retainCount of that string. That means sometime in the future this string will be released which may happen before the dealloc of your object is called.

Declare the string as a retained property.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *xyzProp;
```

and when setting it, use the setter.

```
self.xyzProp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Report error"];
```

The apple generated setter looks somewhat like this,

```
- (void)setXyzProp:(NSMutableString *)aString {
    if (aString == xyzProp) {
        return;
    }
    NSMutableString *oldValue = xyzProp;
    xyzProp = [aString retain];
    [oldValue release];
}
```

Calling `self.xyzProp = ...` is identical to calling, `[self setXyzProp:...]` ensuring that the setter is called which will then call retain on the passed-in string.

**Update**

When setting strings, you almost always want to `copy` instead of `retain`, especially in this case since a `NSMutableString` is being passed. The reason being that the string value may get changed from outside your object without the object knowing which could lead to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`xypProp` by itself is *not* a property — it would have to be the instance variable backing a property. And in that case, yes, that's an error. You're assigning something you don't own to an instance variable, so it will probably vanish out from under you — and releasing it is certainly wrong, since the problem is that you don't own it in the first place. To use the property setter (which would be correct), it would have to be `self.xyzProp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Report error"];`.

Answer (score 0):

`stringWithString:` is returning an autoreleased object, and as you're only using assignment here (not the property), then when you try to release it in the `dealloc` method you will get an error (because you never retained it in this class).

If your xyzProp really is a property, with the retain attribute in its declaration, then you can use the properties setter method as follows:

```
self.xyzProp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Report error"];
```

Which is maybe what you meant to do. If you're still confused, I suggest you refer to the properties programming guide by Apple.

Comment: I just replaced xyzProp with self. xyzProp But still the app seems to be crashing (BAD SIGNAL...)
I am now using self.xyzProp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Report error"];